# Dexie.js indexedDB can't find specified object

Tags: webpack, indexeddb, dexie

I'm adding a indexedDB in my Vue + Laravel application, here's the code that I'm currently using:

```
  export default {
      mixins: [VueGoogleMap.MapElementMixin],
      created() {
          this.eventBus.$on("refresh-map", () => {
              this.fetchHexagons();
          });

          const getAllBuildings = () => Vue.http.get("/sandbox/buildings");

          getAllBuildings().then((result) => {
              const async = Dexie.async;
              const spawn = Dexie.spawn;

              const db = new Dexie("buildings");

              db.version(1).stores({
                  buildings: `++dexie_id, id, name, address, city, nr_units, lat, long, purchased`,
              });

              db.transaction("rw", db.buildings, function* () {
                  result.body.forEach(function*(el) {
                      const a = yield db.buildings.add({
                          id: el.id,
                          name: el.name,
                          address: el.address,
                          city: el.city,
                          nr_units: el.nr_units,
                          lat: el.lat,
                          long: el.long,
                          purchased: el.purchased,
                      });
                  });

                  console.log("done");

              }).catch(function(err) {

                  // Catch any error event or exception and log it:
                  console.error(err.stack || err);
              });
```

As you can see, I'm querying the DB in order to transfer all the buildings in the indexedDB, in order to parse them faster (I need to display them in a map..). The problem is that when I run this code I get the following error:

```
CanvasOverlay.vue?e208:68 Error: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.
    at Transaction.create (dexie.es.js?f8d5:2900)
    at eval (dexie.es.js?f8d5:2222)
    at eval (dexie.es.js?f8d5:1343)
    at callListener (dexie.es.js?f8d5:1026)
    at endMicroTickScope (dexie.es.js?f8d5:1113)
    at IDBOpenDBRequest.eval (dexie.es.js?f8d5:1180)
```

The only package I have installed is Dexie:

```
npm install --save dexie
```

Do I need to install something more or it might be a Webpack problem?

Comment: Can you please change the title of your question so it will be more useful to others? As it currently stands, your title is very broad. Your question is specifically about an issue with dexie, and a particular type of indexedDB error. Please consider mentioning those things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to delete the database and re-run the code. This issue is quite common and happens when a same version (1) is updated without incrementing version number according to [these docs](http://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Understanding-the-basics).

Also, I see another error - you cannot use function* from a forEach() call. Instead use:

```js
    for (let el of result.body) {
      ...
    }
```

or even better:

```js
const itemsToAdd = result.body.map(el => ({
                          id: el.id,
                          name: el.name,
                          address: el.address,
                          city: el.city,
                          nr_units: el.nr_units,
                          lat: el.lat,
                          long: el.long,
                          purchased: el.purchased,
                      }));
return db.buildings.bulkAdd(itemsToAdd);
```